# Magento2 : How to set custom meta title & meta description by observer?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, meta-tags

I want to set meta title , description by the help of observer.
But unable to set data here.
please see my code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_page_config = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config');

echo $_meta_title = strip_tags($_page_config->setTitle("my custom title"));
echo $_meta_description = strip_tags($_page_config->setDescription("my custom description"));
```

Anyone has an idea would me much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to add the below code in [Vendor Name]/[Module Name]/etc/events.xml in your existing module or create a new module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <!-- Product Meta Tags Changes Action -->
    <event name="catalog_controller_product_view">
        <observer name="product__meta_observer" instance="[Vendor Name]\[Module Name]\Observer\SeoMetaObserver"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

After that, you have to create a new observer file which you have mention in events.xml file like:

[Vendor Name][Module Name]\Observer\SeoMetaObserver.php

And add below code:

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor Name]\[Module Name]\Observer;
 
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
 
class SeoMetaObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    const XML_PRODUCT_AUTO_METADESCRIPTION = 'catalog/fields_masks/meta_description';
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;
    
    /**
     * SeoMetaObserver constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    )
    {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }
    
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        $metaDesc = trim($product->getMetaDescription());
        if ($metaDesc == '') {
            if ($product->getShortDescription() != '') {
                $metaDesc = $product->getShortDescription(); //If no SEO Meta Description is set in the product’s information use the Short Description
            } else {
                $configMeta = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PRODUCT_AUTO_METADESCRIPTION, \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE); //If no Short Description is set in the product’s information use configuration settings for the Meta Description
                $string = str_replace("{{","",str_replace("}}","",$configMeta));
                $finalMeta = explode(' ', $string);
                $i = 0;
                foreach ($finalMeta as $meta) {
                    if ($i == 0) {
                        $metaDesc .= $product->getData($meta);
                    } else {
                        $metaDesc .= ' ' . $product->getData($meta);
                    }
                    $i++;
                }
            }
        }
        $product->setMetaDescription($metaDesc);
    }
}
```

Then flush the Magento cache and check the product page meta description tag.

Reference:
https://www.magemonkeys.com/magento-2-product-meta-description-override-how-to-use-short-description-instead-of-products-information/